# CSS table properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, webforms

I am trying to set some styles for objects that are within a table but the problem is that the properties are not being applied to the actual objects.

the .tblData works fine but the label and textbox properties are supposed to be or any ASP.net label or textbox that appears within the table but the CSS doesnt get applied to them.

```
.tblData {
    border: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    height: 200px;
    color: rgb(45,40,128);
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:3px;
    margin-top:3px;

}
/*Class for the labels*/
.tblData label {
    width: 13%;
    color:black;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-family:verdana;
    border-radius:3px;
    border-color:rgba(45,40,128,0.75);
    border-width:1px;

}
/*Class for the data textboxes*/
.tblData textbox {
    border-color: rgba(45,40,128,0.75);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color:rgba(45,40,128,0.10);
    font-family:Verdana;
    border-radius:3px;
}
```

This is the HTML (can't show all of it because the table is massive):

```
<table id="tblAddress" class="tblData">
           <tr>
               <td class="auto-style3">
                   <asp:Label ID="lblACNO" runat="server" Text="ACNO" CssClass="Datalabelcolumn"></asp:Label></td>
               <td class="auto-style2">
                   <asp:TextBox ID="txtACNO" runat="server" CssClass="autosuggest" Width="20%" ToolTip="This is a test tooltip"></asp:TextBox>
               </td>
```

Comment: show your html markup too....css only wont help...or may be jsfiddle is best option!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I have added some HTML from my table as an example.

Comment: Test box renders in input type and label renders in span so change according to it

Comment: Also you need to add `border-style: solid;` or a border will not be shown.

Comment: @connersz, the asp.net server tag and final html output are different. You need to write your CSS again html tags. Please check my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ASP.Net, server tag`<asp:Label>` will be rendered as html `<span>`.

for `<asp:TextBox>` it is `<input type='text'>`

So please change your css selector

from

```
.tblData label {}
.tblData textbox{}
```

to

```
 .tblData span{} or .tblData .Datalabelcolumn{}
 .tblData input[type="text"]{} or .tblData .autosuggest {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying different css class to your Lable and TextBox inside your table (i.e Datalabelcolumn and autosuggest). So it will only apply those properties. Remove them and it will work. Or mention whatever style you need in your "Datalabelcolumn" and "autosuggest" css class for those controls.

Answer (score 0):

add `class="tblData"` to `td` instead of `table`

[**basic demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ubw6/1/)

```
        <td class="tblData">
            <label>this is a label</label>
            <textbox>this is textbox</textbox>
        </td>
```